# Highchart to show progress percentages in horizontal bars with real time data?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, highcharts, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to display the progress of completion of different subjects on a single chart ,where the data of this progress would be fetched in real time from the database .
This progress would be in terms of percentages and i want it to be plotted as horizontal bars. something like this:

[image]

I have tried this :

```
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
            <AxisX Title="Subject Code" IsLabelAutoFit="True" >
            <LabelStyle Angle="-90" Interval="1" />
                <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
            </AxisX>
            <AxisY Title="Progress %" Interval="10" IsLabelAutoFit="True" >

                <MajorGrid Enabled="false" />
            </AxisY>
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
```

code-behind:

```
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            Chart5.Visible = true;
            connection.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select distinct sub_code from [dbname].[dbo].[xyz]",connection);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);


            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                sub_code = row["sub_code"].ToString();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select  checked_percent, unchecked_percent From(select COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*)from[xyz].[dbo].[xyz] where sub_code = @sub_code) as checked_percent from[dbname].[dbo].[xyz]  where CheckBy is not null and sub_code = @sub_code )checked,(select COUNT(*) * 100.0 / (select count(*)from[dbname].[dbo].[xyz] where sub_code = @sub_code)as unchecked_percent from[dbname].[dbo].[xyz]  where CheckBy is  null and sub_code = @sub_code)unchecked", connection);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sub_code", sub_code);

                SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd1);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da1.Fill(ds);

                DataTable ChartData = ds.Tables[0];
                Chart5.DataSource = ChartData;
                Chart5.Series[0].Points.DataBind(ChartData.DefaultView, "sub_code");


                DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(0, Convert.ToDouble(ChartData.Rows[0]["unchecked_percent"]));
                dp.Label = string.Format("unchecked\n{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[0]["unchecked_percent"]);
                Chart5.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);

                dp = new DataPoint(0, Convert.ToDouble(ChartData.Rows[0]["checked_percent"]));
                dp.Label = string.Format("checked\n{0:0.00}%", ChartData.Rows[0]["checked_percent"]);
                Chart5.Series[1].Points.Add(dp);
                connection.Close();


            }

        }
```

I need the y-axis to display the sub_codes but not getting that.

Comment: What type of project are you using? Web Application, Windows Forms, Console Application, WPF Application, other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to add this 1 line of code :

```
     dp.AxisLabel =sub_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Highcharts I'd follow these steps:

- Create two percentage stacked **bar** series (`stacking: percent`). The first one will hold the actual value (e.g. 78) and the second one will be the difference between the first one and 100 (e.g. 22).
- Disable tooltip for the second series using this code in options: `tooltip.pointFormat: false`
- Configure `dataLabels` so that the're on the right side of the bars and they show the percent sign along with the number.
- To understand live updating in Highcharts see the charts from ***Dynamic charts*** section of this page: https://www.highcharts.com/demo

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.stacking
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.dataLabels
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.tooltip.pointFormat

Comment: What are the **sub_codes** in your code?  How do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Sub_codes are basically subject codes .I just want them to be displayed on the y axis where currently u see 2,3,4... (kindly refer to image above).

Comment: The easiest way is to use `categories` (https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories). They start from `0` and their step is `1`, but you can provide empty strings for the first two ones like in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/kL2cpq0p/

Comment: can the categories be fetched from the database? here you are mentioning them inline.

Comment: Yes, but I think that this question might not be quite specific. Fetching from database and initializing Highcharts are two separate processes. You can get categories from DB, save them in a variable and use it in chart's options (`categories: categoriesFromDB`)